# Unable to run Client/Server Socket progam on Virtual Box

Tags: c, websocket, tcp

I have developed a file transfer program using C. It runs on Unix base systems. My machine is Windows. So I have to install a virtual box and install Ubuntu.
I tried to run the server on one machine and the client on another machine.
I used the same wifi networks for both machines. But It does not work.
The following error occurred: -

"Connection is refused"

But when I tried this on the same machine, It worked.

This is the code for the Server.

server.c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>

void error(const char *msg){

    perror(msg);
    exit(1);

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    if(argc < 2){
        fprintf(stderr,"Port number is not provided");
        exit(1);
    }

    int sockfd , newsockfd , portno, n;
    char buffer[255];

    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr , cli_addr;
    socklen_t clilen;

    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(sockfd < 0) {
        error(" Error opening Socket");
    }

    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));

    portno = atoi(argv[1]);

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(portno);

    if(bind(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr))<0){
        error(" Binding Failed.");
    }

    listen(sockfd , 5);  //maximum clients that can connect to the Server = 5

    clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

    newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &cli_addr, &clilen);

    if(newsockfd < 0){
        error(" Error on Accept");
    }

    FILE *fp;
    int ch =0;
    fp =fopen("glad_received.txt", "a");
    int words;
    read(newsockfd, &words, sizeof(int));

    while(ch != words){
        read(newsockfd, buffer, 255);
        fprintf(fp, "%s ", buffer);
        ch++;
    }

    printf(" The file has been received successfully. It is saved by the name glad_received.txt");

    close(newsockfd);
    close(sockfd);
    return 0;

}
```

This is the code for Client.

client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void error(const char *msg) {
    perror(msg);
    exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc != 4) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <filename> <server-IP-address> <port>\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    int sockfd, n;
    struct addrinfo hints, *res, *p;
    char buffer[255];

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    if ((n = getaddrinfo(argv[2], argv[3], &hints, &res)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(n));
        exit(1);
    }

    for (p = res; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol);
        if (sockfd == -1) {
            perror("socket");
            continue;
        }

        if (connect(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
            close(sockfd);
            perror("connect");
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    if (p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to connect\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    freeaddrinfo(res);

    bzero(buffer, 255);

    FILE *f;
    int words = 0;

    f = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    if (f == NULL) {
        error("Error opening file");
    }

    char c;
    while ((c = getc(f)) != EOF) {
        fscanf(f, "%s ", buffer);
        if (isspace(c) || c == '\t') {
            words++;
        }
    }

    rewind(f);

    write(sockfd, &words, sizeof(int));

    char ch;
    while (ch != EOF) {
        fscanf(f, "%s", buffer);
        write(sockfd, buffer, 255);
        ch = fgetc(f);
    }

    printf("The file has been successfully sent.\n");

    close(sockfd);
    fclose(f);
    return 0;
}
```

These are the executing code for,

```
server.c :-

 ./server 9898

client.c :-

 ./client Glad.txt 10.0.2.15 9898
```

(Glad.txt is the file that I want to send.)

This is how I find the IP address.
[image: This is how I find the IP address.]

Comment: *" I tried to run the server on one machine and the client on another machine."* - please specify in terms of IP addresses what you are trying to do. Right now one can only see that the client connects to 10.0.2.15 - but it is not clear from your description if this is the IP address where the server runs or the IP address where the client runs. Apart from that there might be firewalls in between which block the connection. And client and server might even be in networks which cannot reach each other, depending on the unknown config of the VM and host.